"Could not write file" Error showing when importing a Maven project in Eclipse
I am not able to import a maven project in eclipse. I have generated a maven project using https://start.spring.io/. When I tried to import the project using "Existing Maven project" its is showing an error. Tried to delete .metadata folder from the directory but still not able to import the project. Maven Project import error 

Never ever delete the .metadata folder or other files you do not know about. Doing this can wreck your workspace and cause data loss. In contrast, the use of a fresh workspace is safe. Please help prevent this hoax from spreading further by not even mentioning it in your question. The error message says Could not write file: C:\Users\Spring Framework and Spring Boot\learn-spring-framework_1\.project., probably due to missing permissions for this directory. You therefore need to change the permissions for this directory or use a different directory.

C:\Users\Spring Framework and Spring Boot looks like the home directory of the user Spring Framework and Spring Boot which is a strange user name and probably not your real user name. This might be the cause of the missing file permissions. Better put the project into your own home directory.

Thank you very much @howlger. Changing the directory resolved the issue. In some other blogs, some people suggested deleting .metadata folders to avoid this kind of error. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Deleting the .metadata folder can cause serious damage. So far I have only seen that this hoax is being spread on Stack Overflow only and that it causing real problems for real people. To be clear, no one with some basic knowledge, nor the documentation, is recommending this hoax. Be aware that also just mentioning it in a question will spread the hoax further.
